# How to find out whether a file is currently growing in Java (OS Independent)

Tags: java, windows, file, filesystems

I'm trying to find a cross-platform way of reliably telling whether a file has finished being copied (by an external process).

Previously, on OSX/Linux I'd simply been checking

```
File file = new File("path/to/file");
file.length()
```

then waiting for a few seconds and checking it again to see if it had changed.

This doesn't work on Windows however, as the method always returns the size of the full file (i.e what it will eventually be once copied).

I've also tried checking the lastModified timestamp, but this doesn't appear to change either.

Comment: There is no such feature on any OS. What are you trying to do?

Comment: can you ask the external process to post a flag file once it is done writing data into it to signal completion?  that is how i typically do it or ask external data providers to do it when exchanging feeds and such

Comment: Do you create a new file object each time? If not, try that, it's possible that the File object you're creating is caching the last modified time.

Comment: @foampile Unfortunately not, the external process is completely out of our control and ability to change

Comment: @Brigham Doesn't help unfortunately - file.length will return the full size on Windows regardless of when the File object is created

Comment: that's a pretty bad design on their end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by calculating the checksum and hash of the file (rather than the length) at two different points in time and checking whether they had changed in order to determine whether the file was still being written to.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to try to open the file for writing, using an "appending" `FileOutputStream` - if you can do that, it's unlikely that another process is *also* writing to the file. You don't need to write any data, of course - just create the stream.

(Edited to remove the idea which is already in the question, of using `lastModified`.)

Comment: As stated in my question, File.lastModified doesn't seem to change throughout the process on Windows.

FileOutputStream does throw an Exception on Windows (not on the Unix-based systems), so I can put a platform-specific method in that uses that, but I'd ideally like a single solution that works everywhere.

Comment: @ThomShutt: Darn, I only saw the `length()` part of the question. Can you really append to a file which is being written by another process on Unix? That sounds odd - but I guess it depends on the file-writing code.

Comment: Interestingly, this method works on local files, but I am still able to get a lock on files that are being written to on a network directory for some reason.